# C# to convert any string to a safe cross-platform file name?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, cross-platform

Given any .NET string, what is the C# algorithm to convert it to a safe file name on any operating system? Windows, iOS, Android, Linux? The goal would be to preserve the original string as much as possible while making it safe for use as a file name on any platform.

Comment: Base36 might work well.  You wouldn't want to assume your file system is case-sensitive.

Comment: You also need to consider the file name length, since it differs from system to system.

Comment: I do not know of any built in method that you can use.  I generated my own checks for Windows to Linux.

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on conversion? Like "should resemble original string" or "1-to-1 mapping with original string" or length or character set restrictions? In very generic case conversion will be as useful as creating new guid... Like converting 10K long string of Chinese characters to pure ASCII ...

Comment: Yes, the goal would be to preserve the original string as much as possible while making it safe for use as a file name on any platform.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the GetInvalidFileNameChars() method from the System.IO.Path class.

```
System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()
```

Comment: Does this handle the case where a Windows file name could be `"Space Here"` and for Linux it converts it to `"Space\ Here"`?  I know I ran into spacing issues with Windows to Linux before, just curious